# Why does pushbutton not get detected all the time that it's pressed?

Tags: arduino

Currently I'm trying to develop a simple application to blink some LED and to change state according to the input given by the pushbutton. This means that I have a LED blinking and whenever I press the button I want to change the state of the LED either to be always ON or to resume the blinking.

This is the circuit that I built:

[image: Arduino Circuit]

This is the code that I have now:

```
int currentState = HIGH;
int reading;
int previousState = LOW;

long time = 0; // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int i = 4; i < 8; i++){
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  reading = digitalRead(2);

  if (reading == HIGH && previousState == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    Serial.println("The button was pressed");
    time = millis();
  }

  previousState = reading;

  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(1000);

}
```

So my difficult now, is that when I press the pushbutton it doesn't get always detected. Sometimes it prints to the terminal and other times it does nothing. Why?

Comment: Because you are blinking the LED and not reading the button.

Comment: @gre_gor have you seen this line `reading = digitalRead(2);`?

Comment: Yes. It's getting called only once every 2 seconds.

Comment: What do you propose to overcome that?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay